# After picking a color in Photoshop, my color always turns grey

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am trying to draw a rectangle, one per layer and let each have a different color. My problem is that each shape is grey. I choose the new color on the color chart and I click OK, it defaults back to a grey.

Answer (score 5):

You need to change the document color mode.

Go to Image -> Mode -> RGB or another color mode that isn't Grayscale.

Comment: One other possibility is that a Layer **Mask** is selected instead of the Layer itself.

Comment: This is not the issue they're having, I'm going through the same thing and RGB is already selected. When trying to adjust the hue and saturation of the rectangle it just changes to different shades of gray, it never turns colored. I check again and again and RGB is the selected mode for all layers. Thing is I have another photoshop file where I can easily adjust the color of the rectangle to make a yellow background for text.

Comment: If it still doesn't work go to image -> mode -> 32 bit